# Django REST framework without model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to use Django REST framework to create an API to call different methods. I read the guide of [django-rest-framework][1] to work with this framework, but I still have some questions.

I have no model I get my data from an external database. I want to try first something simple:

- Get all list of project
- Get the data from one project

For that I create new app I include in the setting file and in my view.py I include that for the fist case

```
def connect_database():
  db = MySQLdb.connect(host='...', port=, user='...', passwd='...', db='...')
  try:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM proj_cpus')
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    # all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
    all_rows = []
    for row in iter_row(cursor):
      all_rows.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
  finally:
    db.close()
  return all_rows

def iter_row(cursor, size= 1000):
  while True:
    results = cursor.fetchmany(size)
    if not results:
      break
    for item_result in results:
      yield item_result


class cpuProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
  serializer_class = serializers.cpuProjectsSerializer

  def list(self, request):
    all_rows = connect_database()
    name_project = []  
    for item_row in all_rows:
      name_project.append(item_row['project'])
    name_project = list(sorted(set(name_project)))
    serializer = serializers.cpuProjectsSerializer(instance=name_project, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

my serializers file I have this

```
class cpuProjectsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  project = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)


  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.project = validated_data.get('project', instance.project)
    return instance
```

Now when I execute this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hpcAPI`

I obtain this error

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `project` on serializer `cpuProjectsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance.
Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'project'.
```

I look for in google and I change this

`serializers.cpuProjectsSerializer(instance=name_project, many=False)` for

```
serializers.cpuProjectsListSerializer(instance=name_project, many=False)
```

but I obtain the same error!

any idea about that!

Thanks in adavances

Comment: Is that how your code actually looks, or is there an issue with the indentation? Because if it does look like then, then you probably have `SyntaxError`.

Comment: thanks @Games Brainiac I edit the entire request, maybe when I paste I move some line!, I have no problem with the indentation, I have a problem with serializers file, in my case I have an  empty file , only have an import line. I don't know how exactly have to be this file to return a list of project, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class).You don't have to have a model for create a Serializer class.You can define some serializers field then use them. You should not import CPUProjectsViewSet and also define it in below

```
from mysite.hpcAPI.serializers import CPUProjectsViewSet

class CPUProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
"""
return all project name
"""
    all_rows = connect_database()
```

Comment: thanks for your advise @Windsooon, I change my code and I obtain this error `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `project` on serializer `cpuProjectsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance.
Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'project'.` any idea about that